# Why Ubuntu can't play MP3 files by default

Tags: sound, mp3, license

Why Ubuntu can't play MP3 files by default? I was going to ask a bit more detailed question but I won't. It's just ridiculous.

Comment: THIS is ridiculous : http://mp3licensing.com/help/developers.html

Comment: This is like patenting 2+2=4. I have no more questions. I don't expect any answer anymore. This is enough. I'm going to boycott mp3.

Comment: Good news a lot of the patents run out in 2017.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3

Comment: yay! A win for the FOSS community! \('o')/

Comment: The only free audio formats I know are Ogg and FLAC, but there should be more.

Comment: @Elric yeah, well, imagine doing large scale psycho-acoustics research without money. It's not about code, it's about scientists, audio hardware etc. etc. etc. FLAC is about loseless compression (it's just code/ideas), ogg is a container

Comment: @Elric, maybe you think some country/institute should just take taxpayers money and develop free software/hardware/acoustic models/measurements and have 'thanks' in return? I guess, though, measurements were opensourced

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see why in this article of the community wiki:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats

The introduction of the article gives the logic behind this decision:

> Ubuntu strives to make all of the most important software available to its users automatically. However patent and copyright restrictions (see Ubuntu License Policy) complicate distribution of software to support non-free formats...
>
> Ubuntu’s commitment to only include completely free software by default means that proprietary media formats are not configured “out of the box”. See Ubuntu’s Free Software Philosophy and the Free Formats page for a more comprehensive discussion of these issues.

### TL;DR:

MP3 is not a free media format, which creates licensing issues and conflicts with the Free Software Philosophy of ubuntu and linux in general.

Comment: That's insane. I've created my own MP3 encoder/decoder as one of my programming assignments at my university and no one has ever told me that it is illegal.

Comment: @pvc See US patent [5,703,999](https://www.google.com/patents/US5703999) which doesn't expire until December 30, 2017 (as well as [several others](https://madfileformatscience.garymcgath.com/2016/04/05/mp3patent/)).

Answer (score 0):

Please search for **Gstreamer** at **Software Centre** and you will find some Gstreamer pluggins and codecs already installed but some are still not installed at all.These are often called "Ugly" packages. Please install the remaining uninstalled one and you will be fine.

Using Ubuntu 18.04.1 Budgie Desktop Environment

Thank You

[Gstreamer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bl41Y.png)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You may want to elaborate on the names of the plugins to install.

Comment: Edited see the image all of same names "Gstreamer Multimedia Codecs"