# Read .mp3 files from an USB stick, is it possible?

Tags: usb, sound, mp3, flac

Is it possible to configure an USB stick (or a external disk) to access/use the hardware of my computer, which I know works, but can't be accessed/used by Ubuntu, to obtain an audio output up from the computer's jack to my ears? To read mp3 files and flac files.

Comment: You mean, auto play for USB drive using an mp3 player ? Is audio working for you if you use speakers or head set ?

Comment: Not since I installed Ubuntu on my computer. But I know the hardware of it works, from a previous Windows installed, used to play sound.

Comment: Make the sound work after installing required drivers. After that, you can play music stored in USB drive

Comment: **Yes, that's possible**: You just need to install a persistent Ubuntu Live system on the USB stick, boot it, get the sound to work there and you're done. However, you could just fix the sound issues of your normal installation…

Comment: I think this question is clear, at least it is now. The computer has sound output hardware and has been successfully used to play music files on a previous Windows system. Just installing Ubuntu and attempting to play them does not succeed. The goal is to play the files on Ubuntu, *including* from a live environment run from a USB flash drive. (This requires codecs and persistence, as covered in [sudodus's excellent answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/953643/22949).) Although this could potentially be edited further to make it clearer, that may not even be necessary. I'm voting to reopen this now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You need additional codecs to play `mp3` and `flac` files in Ubuntu

Drivers or maybe you mean codecs - Well, you don't install them on the USB stick (unless indirectly, if your whole system is on a USB stick). We install them into the operating system (which is usually in an internal drive).

The linux drivers are different from Windows drivers. The linux drivers are normally bundled with the linux kernel except in special cases, for example for some graphics and wifi chips/cards, where proprietary drivers are available. *Usually the linux drivers for the audio hardware work well.*

The codecs code/decode the [compressed] data in audio and video files, and many of these formats are subject to licensing, and the codecs are not [FOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software).

- *Please install a program package, that will provide the necessary codecs* for `mp3`, `mp4`, `flac` and other multimedia formats. Ubuntu can not deliver them with the operating system due to [licensing issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779222/why-ubuntu-cant-play-mp3-files-by-default?rq=1), but you can install them as an end user. Use the following commands in a terminal window (or a package manager with a graphical user interface),

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
  ```
- Sometimes you must tweak the audio system in order to make Ubuntu play aloud. You can do that via the icon with the cog wheel on the left panel, 'System Settings' and then click on the icon 'Sound'.

  In some computers it is more difficult, and maybe you want a more powerful tool. If this is the case, please install `pavucontrol`

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository universe  # and press Enter
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install pulseaudio pavucontrol
  ```

  and use it with the following command line (or via dash,type **p** to find 'PulseAudio Volume Control')

  ```
  pavucontrol
  ```
- Many people like the multimedia player VLC. It is available for all common operating systems, Linux, Windows, MacOS ...

  In Ubuntu it is easiest and most reliable to install it with the following command lines (or via a package manager with a graphical user interface),

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install vlc
  ```

---

*This is the classical way in Linux (and Ubuntu is a Linux operating system). **We install additional software packages via repositories**, and after that they become integrated with the operating system. For example, they share common library packages, and they are updated & upgraded automatically, when a new version is uploaded to the Ubuntu repositories.*

---

### Persistent live Ubuntu system

You can install a persistent live Ubuntu system in the USB stick. This way you can install the 'restricted-extras' and the `mp3` files, boot from the USB stick and play. This system will be portable between most PC computers (depending on what version you install and how you install it). See the following link and links from it,

- [Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389)

It is possible 'to squeeze it into an 8GB pendrive with a shoehorn', but I would recommend a fast USB 3 pendrive with at least 16GB. If you select an Ubuntu community flavour with a light-weight desktop environment, for example Lubuntu, it will be faster and need less drive space, which helps in a small and/or slow USB stick.

- [help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_speed](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_speed)

The tool **mkusb** can do the job almost automatically for you. Install mkusb with the following commands in a terminal window. If you run standard Ubuntu, you need an extra instruction to get the repository Universe. (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu have the repository Universe activated automatically.)

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe  # only for standard Ubuntu

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
```

See the following links for more details,

- [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)
- [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

When you have created the persistent live Ubuntu system, and you have booted into it, you should install the same extra packages as you would install in a system that resides in the internal drive,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

and/or maybe

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe  # and press Enter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio pavucontrol
```

Comment: I want to solve the problem (get audio output) "through" ubuntu, but seems like I can't solve it "with" Ubuntu. I know the hardware works, but Ubuntu doesn't support it. And I actually don't want to solve it the classical way (add some stuff to the OS  of the computer for enwiden supportability). I would like to be able to read mp3 files everytime I plug my USB in. Your answer 2. and the first way of the Edit fits great.

Comment: @SandroSivsivadzé, I think most people go the classical way. They install the 'ubuntu-restricted-extras' and use the built-in media player or install VLC. There is no easy way to solve the problems by adding *only* the content of  the 'ubuntu-restricted-extras' to the USB stick.

Comment: @SandroSivsivadzé, I have tried to make a detailed description of the steps, that should help you play `mp3` and `flac` files from your USB stick. I hope and think that it will be enough with the 'ubuntu-restricted-extras' , but maybe you have to tweak the audio system too. And you may prefer VLC to the built-in media player. Good luck, and please come back if you need more help :-)